# Returning data to activity, intent.putExtra or contentprovider?

Tags: android

I have an activity and an intentService, My intentServie fetches some data from web and need pass it back to activity. I am currently using ResultReceiver in service to pass data back to activity.

> **Is it appropriate for larg data set ?**
>
> **Do Intents have any limit on the data passed through putExtra ?**
>
> **How should I update UI (ListView) on main activity ?** (won't it be hanged on large dataSet ?
>
> **Should I use contentProvider instead ?** If yes , how would I query large dataset in UI thread (without causing ANR)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No, its not appropriate to send large data via Intent
- As far as i remember, once i tried to send bytes data which was above
  1MB and it wasn't able to do this. So i believe, it does have data
  limit
- Since you are using *ResultReceiver*, so the best is to use its
  **onReceiveResult** to get notified with the results and do any required update in your UI
- If your app doesn't offer its data to other apps then I guess its too
  much fuss

Comment: if I don't use intents to pass large data (as you said) then how should I pass (without using contentprovider) ? other thing I am currently receiving in onReceiveResult but won't it hang the UI if I update list in OnReceiveResult (its too in UI thread I guess).

Comment: Updating a list shouldn't hang, and if it does then use AsyncTask. Regarding large intents, i would recommend you to save your bundle or Parcelable objects in a private file at a location using `getFilesDir()`, notify the other side with the regular method (intent via broadcast, ResultReceiver or whatever your pattern is) and then read that file to construct object(s) and finally delete that file. I did this in one of my project and it works flawlessly without any delaying issues. In this way, your intent will remain small in size